# Mantener distancia entre objetos en Java

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo 3 pelotas dentro de un `JPanel` que se mueven en velocidades aleatorias. Hasta ahí todo está bien. Pero quisiera que las pelotas siempre estén a una distancia igual, por ejemplo que la distancia vertical entre cada una sea de 50 pixeles.

```
package jFrameLluvia; 
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;

public class Gota {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int radio;
    private int retraso;
    private Random r;
    private int velocidad;

    public Gota() {
        this.r = new Random();
        this.radio = 5;
        this.x = 100;
        this.y = r.nextInt(250 + 2 * radio) - radio;
        this.retraso = r.nextInt(20) + 1;
        this.velocidad = (radio + 1) / radio;
    }

    public void moverse(int ancho) {
        if (retraso == 0) {
            if (x < ancho)
                x += velocidad;
            else {
                x = 150 + radio;
                this.retraso = (5) + 1;
            }
        } else
            retraso--;
    }

    public void dibujar(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(x - radio, y - radio, 2 * radio, 2 * radio);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Kelsy, Bienvenido a SO en español, puedes agregar el codigo que actualmente usas, asi recibiras mejores respuestas que te ayudaran a resolver tu problema.

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverflow en español, Kelsy. No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta. El título dice que necesitas ayuda con el movimiento horizontal pero el texto indica que las pelotas siempre deberían estar a una distancia X, por ejemplo de 50 pixeles. ¿Qué es lo que necesitas exactamente?

Comment: Lo que necesito exactamente como dice Luiggi es que la distancia entre cada pelota sea de 50 pixeles por favor ayudenme :c

Answer (score 3):

Puedes crear un constructor en tu clase `Gota` que reciba el valor de Y como argumento y utilizar los demás valores por defecto para el resto de los campos. Aquí un ejemplo:

```
public class Gota {
    //los otros campos permanecen tal cual
    private Random r = new Random();

    public Gota() {
        //se aprovecha utilizar this(arg) para delegar trabajo a otro constructor
        this.(r.nextInt(250 + 2 * radio) - radio);
    }

    public Gota(int y) {
        this.radio = 5;
        this.x = 100;
        this.y = y;
        this.retraso = r.nextInt(20) + 1;
        this.velocidad = (radio + 1) / radio;
    }

    //resto de métodos en la clase
}
```

Y luego puedes crear las otras instancias de `Gota` basado en una instancia que ya tengas:

```
Gota gota1 = new Gota();
Gota gota2 = new Gota(gota1.getY());
```